# Is there a way to dynamically add pandoc or html code to a .RMD file?

Tags: r, layout, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I am trying to do render an html file in RMD that can dynamically produce pandoc or html code. Specifically, I want there to be two columns with text on the left and a plot on the right and then a plot that takes up the whole middle. I can do that fine (see the code below) but I would like to do that n times. Here is my attempt to do it with the part I want to reproduce n times on top and my attempt at doing so on the bottom. Note that this is a .RMD file, I got the code from here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/multi-column.html

````
---
output: html_document
---


# Start part I want to reproduce n times

:::: {style="display: flex;"}

::: {}
Here is the **first** Div.

```{r echo = FALSE}
cat(paste0("Here is some text that I would like to display on the left"))
```
:::

::: {}
And this block will be put on the right:

```{r echo = FALSE}
plot(iris[, -5])
```
:::

::::

Then something that takes up the entire space

```{r}
plot(cars)
```

# End part I want to reproduce n times



# Start my attempt at solving the problem

```{r}
n = 4
generate_pattern <- function() {
  cat(paste0(":::: {style=\"display: flex;\"}\n"))
  cat(paste0("::: {}\n"))
  cat(paste0("Here is the **first** Div.\n"))
  cat(paste0("```{r echo = FALSE}\n"))
  cat(paste0("cat(paste0(\"Here is some text that I would like to display on the left\"))\n"))
  cat(paste0("```\n"))
  cat(paste0("::: {}\n"))
  cat(paste0("And this block will be put on the right:\n"))
  cat(paste0("```{r echo = FALSE}\n"))
  cat(paste0(plot(iris[, -5]), "\n"))
  cat(paste0("```\n"))
  cat(paste0("::: \n"))
  cat(paste0(plot(cars)))
}

# Generate the pattern n times
for (i in 1:n) {
  generate_pattern()
}
```
````

I'm also open to alternative solutions that use html code. Thanks!